# btoa function how to use in Javascript

Tags: java, selenium

I want to automated below code using Selenium and Java, but whenever I am trying to use window.btoa its giving me syntax error can someone help me how to achieve this in Java with selenium.

please find below code to be automated

```js
var obj={Name:"Automation"}
JSON.stringnify{obj}
window.encodeURIComponent{JSON.strignify(obj)};
btoa(window.encodeURIComponent(JSON.strignify(obj)))
```

Comment: where is the code you forgot to add the code\

Comment: There are several typos in the code, such as _stri**gn**ify_, use of `{` instead of `(`, etc

Comment: @BharatiBelgaonkar Where is `window.btoa` within your code trials?

Comment: I got this code snippet from functional team to automate.

Comment: @BharatiBelgaonkar, try `"Name":"Automation"` instead of `Name:"Automation"`

Comment: @BharatiBelgaonkar - https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html might help you

Comment: This code is Javascript, what has this to do with Java? What does it mean to "automate the code"? What are you actually asking?

Comment: @Henry - I guess she want to write some test against this javascript code with the help of selenium+java. Bharathi, better to make it clear what's the exact requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There is spelling mistake and some brackets you used I changed to correct format.

```
var obj={Name:"Automation"}
JSON.stringify(obj)
window.encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj));
btoa(window.encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj)))
```

Can you try this ?